# Preprocess a model field before it is inserted using the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I using the Django admin interface to be able to easily modify the entries in an existing MySQL database I have. One of my tables contains a password column which contains the hashed password for a user. Now, when I come to create a new user using the admin panel, I have to calculate the password hash externally and then paste that in to the admin panel. Is there anyway I can provide some sort of "pre-insert hook" so that I can enter the password directly, and the hook calculate the hash and pass that on to the admin panel to be saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [override the admin form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form), to use a form like [AdminPasswordChangeForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L366) which validates the new passwords match, and then in its `save` method sets the password accordingly:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    password = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
    self.user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        self.user.save()
    return self.user
```

You could also override the save method on the user, but that's a bit more of a sledgehammer approach.